# Chrome Extension to Modify request headers based on Public IP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a small Chrome Extension to add a header when a user is on one of our Public IP address. I am relatively new to javascript, and could use a little help.

Here is the function to get the public IP address:

```
function getIP(){
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json",
        function(data){
            if(data.query == 'xxx.x.xxx.xxx'){var indist = 1;}else{var indist = 0;} 
            console.log(indist);
            return(indist);
        }); 
}
```

When I retrieve the Pubic IP

```
var indist = getIP();
```

Then the modification of headers in the Chrome Extension.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(


function(details) {
        if(indist === 1){
        details.requestHeaders.push({name:"X-YouTube-Edu-Filter",value:"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"});
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};}

},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},["requestHeaders", "blocking"]

);
```

This is my first shot at it, and I am not getting the results, I would like. Ideally, when a user makes a request for anything on Youtube, I would like to check the users Public IP Address once, then add the header based on that address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `getIP` does not actually return anything, because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous.

Your code looks like this:

```
function getIP(){
  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", someFunction); 
}
```

And this reads as "queue up the request, and when it's finished call `someFunction`". Then the statement terminates, and your function `getIP` ends without returning anything.

The value you `return` in your callback is, therefore, lost.

Additionally, your scoping is wrong:

```
if(data.query == 'xxx.x.xxx.xxx') {
  /* scope begins */
  var indist = 1; // Local, only exists within this branch!
  /* scope ends */
} else {
  var indist = 0;
} 
console.log(indist); // Is not related to above, probably undefined
```

---

As a simple fix, since you're using a global variable anyway in your `onBeforeSendHeaders` handler, just assign it inside the callback:

```
function getIP(){
  $.getJSON(
    "http://ip-api.com/json",
    function(data) {
      if(data.query == 'xxx.x.xxx.xxx') { 
        indist = 1; // GLOBAL variable
      } else {
        indist = 0;
      } 
      console.log(indist);
    }
  );
}
```

---

That said, you probably want to limit the damage your code does. Running blocking code on EVERY SINGLE network request will slow Chrome to a crawl. Rewrite your code to only enable the handler if the condition is met, and then probably only run it on YouTube requests.

```
function getIP(){
  $.getJSON(
    "http://ip-api.com/json",
    function(data) {
      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.removeListener(addHeader);
      if(data.query == 'xxx.x.xxx.xxx') { 
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
          addHeader,
          {urls: ["*://*.youtube.com/*"]},
          ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]
        );
      }
    }
  );
}

function addHeader(details) {
  details.requestHeaders.push({name:"X-YouTube-Edu-Filter",value:"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"});
  return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. You have helped immensely!